# Unable to bind to a port on Openshift

Tags: java, activemq-classic, openshift

I am running an embedded activemq message server in my application on openshift. According to [this](https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port), you can only bind on `15000 - 35530`. I've tried doing the following, but it's throwing a serious error. What could be the issue?

**I am using spring**. This is a part in my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<amq:broker brokerName="tentacle-broker" start="true">
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:amqPersistenceAdapter directory="/var/lib/openshift/username/jbossews-2.0/jbossews-2.0/activemq2" maxFileLength="32mb"/>
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://127.10.180.129:15001"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

**This is the error that i'm having**

```
WARNING: could not generate unique stub
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
        at org.apache.activemq.util.IdGenerator.<clinit>(IdGenerator.java:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.<clinit>(RegionBroker.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createRegionBroker(BrokerService.java:1830)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createRegionBroker(BrokerService.java:1824)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createBroker(BrokerService.java:1781)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getBroker(BrokerService.java:766)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:497)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.autoStart(BrokerService.java:463)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProces
r.java:293)
va:130)
ava:394)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1405)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
:
```

Comment: The port may be in use, the user you use to execute OpenShift doesn't have enough privileges to open a new port or there's another application that blocks yours to open the port.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza According to Openshift documentation, i am free to bind on that port within my application. There is no other binding on the port `15001`. I'm still confused why it's not permitted.

Comment: Again, this is not an OpenShift problem, it is a user/external application problem that blocks OpenShift to open a new port. For example, a firewall can block your application to bind a new port for security purposes. By knowing this, your problem is not even directly related to programming.

Comment: Please check this url https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1038-i-cant-bind-to-a-port and this url https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift. It was explicitly stated, i wouldn't know it i need to do port forwarding.

Comment: You don't understand the possible causes of the problem nor even try to find the real root cause. Voting to close.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Before you conclude on an issue you don't understand or vote someone down, try make some research. Check this post and see for yourself. https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/problems-enabling-jmx-in-activemq

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu were you ever able to finally solve this?

Comment: pls update if you have found an answer to this problem! tnx!

Answer (score 0):

In Openshift, you may only bind to the port that the server allocates for you.  Typically that is the value of the environment variable $OPENSHIFT_JBOSS_PORT (it varies between cartridges) and the value differs between gears.  Binding to any other port will be reported as an SELinux policy violation and denied.

Comment: The port is usually 8080 which my tomcat is already using. I actually used `diy`. In my `diy`, i have both `activemq` and `tomcat`. The `activemq` was setup to run on `tcp` port `16005` which according to `openshift` is open. I discovered that the `activemq` does not start i guess that's the reason i had `permission denied exception` unless there is any other reason. So i don't think i can bind on the same port `8080` twice.

Comment: I created another application for the message server using the example at https://www.openshift.com/blogs/activemq-on-paas. The message server started, but my application running in tomcat couldn't connect to it. I tried connecting to `tcp 15005` and `http 8080` but couldn't get connection. The first i.e `tcp 15005` threw `java.net.NoRouteToHostException` exception and the second `Permission denied exception`.

Comment: @Uchenna Nwanyanwu: Did you solved this problem? I am getting the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314900/how-to-open-tcp-port-in-openshift