# BindException for outbound requests

Tags: java, jboss7.x, openshift

When making outbound request throught java (using `apache.commons.httpclient`), I am getting `Permission denied`.
Following is the root cause from jboss logs:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
       at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:598)
       at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.bind(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:114)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.bind(SSLSocketImpl.java:64)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:430)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:142)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
       at com.killer923.dataFetcher.net.http.HttpRequestDispatcher.sendGETRequest(HttpRequestDispatcher.java:44)
```

I tried using `curl` for fetching page when connected to gear via ssh and it is working fine and is able to fetch data properly.

What am I doing wrong? do I need to specify outgoing port while making the request?

Comment: Nothing to do HTTP. The low-level TCP layer was unable to bind your process to a local port and the reason was lack of permission by the system.

Comment: Take a look at this post here as I think it answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651606/unable-to-bind-to-a-port-on-openshift

Comment: I guess I found the right article : https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/commons-httpclient-permission-denied

Comment: You should post the answer that you found and mark it as correct so others with the same question can get it answered.  You might also provide some of the code you are using, not just the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **simplest way** to resolve the issue was to upgrade the apache commons httpclient to version 4+.

For me, version 4.3.5 worked. Here is the maven entry:

```
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3.5</version>
```

There are also some changes required while fetching the data.

The **other** way, a more complex one, seeks to override the Socket Connection Factory used within the client. I did not try this way, but hope this link helps: 
https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/commons-httpclient-permission-denied