# How to bind DatagramSocket to particular port in Openshift

Tags: java, networking, tcp, openshift, datagram

I am running siple java jar service on openshift which tried to connect with DatagramSocket and Getting this Exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:96)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:397)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:251)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:304)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:276)
at com.gasmps.service.TerminationListener.run(EmailService.java:542)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know this is port permission problems but i tried with port like 8000,8443,15005,16005 but getting same how could i resolve this? How i can know all open port that can i use in my application.

Edit: My jboss server is already running in the same application and I don't want to create separate application for these jar service bcos I have to run this jar from my application from remote location.

Answer (score 0):

Iv looked into this before after having the same issue and discovered the answer on stack-overflow before:

> In Openshift, you may only bind to the port that the server allocates
>   for you. Typically that is the value of the environment variable
>   $OPENSHIFT_JBOSS_PORT (it varies between cartridges) and the value
>   differs between gears. Binding to any other port will be reported as
>   an SELinux policy violation and denied.
>   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651606/unable-to-bind-to-a-port-on-openshift)
>   **The port is usually 8080**
>
> you can bind your app to 8080 (not to 8000 or 8443), all traffic >received on 8000 and 8443 will be routed by the proxy to your app >listening on 8080.

This worked for me, but let me know how it goes and if it still doesn't work i'll try and help.

Comment: you mean i have to run TCP service on 8080 but my jboss server is already running on it when i tried on this port still getting the same exception